# TFS/Visual studio 2010: Clear cached password for TFS in Visual Studio 2010, Need it to ask me to login again

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, credentials

I am using Windows 7 and i installed TFS Server and connected to it from my VS 2010 install. It prompted me for a password so I entered the admin password.

All went well, now i added myself as a user but i can't get it to ask me to login again. It is remembering (caching) the password. Hence it always logs me in as Administrator.

I search the Internet and some people recommend ClearCred.exe which ships with VS SDK but it doesn't anymore ...

And then checking the managed credentials in windows 7, i have also checked this and i see nothing with regards to my cached TFS password.

I also tried removing the TFS server connection from VS 2010 and readding it .. but it remembers me as Administrator.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It should only be remembering the password in the credentials manager, there shouldn't be other places to remember - could you post a screenshot that indicates that you're authenticated as administrator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open the Start Menu and type "Manage Network Passwords" and open the control panel applet that shows up in the results. Then, you should see the credentials in the list where you can expand the item and "Remove from vault."

Comment: No I already checked this, on windows 7 its called network credentials and its not there :-(

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Nothing's shown in the Credential Manager

Comment: There were two credentials that I had to remove. One under "Windows Credentials", and another under "Generic Credentials".

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove TFS credentials from **Windows Vault** to clear and force to ask new TFS credentials in Visual Studio

1. Go to **Control Panel** (**Start -> Control Panel**).
2. Click **User Accounts** ( or **User Accounts and Family Safety->User Accounts** in **Windows 7** Machine)
3. Click **Credential Manager** (or **Manage your credentials**)
4. In **Credential Manager** page, you can see the two type of credentials

   i. Windows Credentials
   ii. Generic Credentials
5. Click on two credentials modify link, click the link **Remove from vault** to remove stored TFS credentials.

Now, When you login into Visual Studio you will be asked to give credentials to connect TFS.

**Note**: Don't forgot to uncheck the option **Remember my credentials** to force to ask credentials for every TFS connections.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after much googling found this link which fixed my problem i hope it works for you aswell.

http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-remember-my-password-with-tfs.html